# Numba does not increase performance as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, numba

I have painstakingly translated some function in my code from non-Numba to Numba. I did this to get a time boost as I am programming a Quadtree to calculate area of a set of intersecting circles. However, I did NOT get an increase in efficiency. To the contrary, the efficiency *decreases* when I uncomment the jit decorator! The entire code takes about 1 second without decorator and about 3 seconds with decorator. I make repeated calls of two Numba functions within another loop that contains objects which I could not convert into Numba format.

The entire piece of codes is hundreds of lines long, so I will provide a minimal example that illustrates one of the key operations in my algorithm (comparing elements within Numpy arrays).
Python version is `2.7.15` and numba version is `0.41.0+0.gf118cda06.dirty`.

```py
import numpy  as     np
import numba
from datetime import datetime
from numba    import jit  

@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    a = np.array([0.3, 0.5])
    b = np.array([0.4, 0.6])
    c = (a[0] < b[1])
    return c
start = datetime.now()
c     = test()
end   = datetime.now()
diff  = end - start 
print "c is", c, diff.microseconds, "microseconds"
```

When `@jit(nopython=True)` decorator is **uncommented** (as in the code snippet) I get:

`c is True 0 microseconds`

When it is **commented**, I get:

`c is True 153000 microseconds`

Why is it so unfavorable?

Comment: Can you try to call test a 1000 times or more instead of one, to see if it's some initialization issue?

Comment: I executed it 10000000 times and it stopped after 3.974 sec with numba decorator compared to 19.226 sec without it. So, as user2357112 says, that is probably a simple compilation cost. Seems fixed to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numba.jit` is called `jit` because it's a *JIT*. As in, just-in-time compilation. [It doesn't compile anything until the first call to the function.](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#lazy-compilation) You are timing compilation costs.

It is possible to make Numba compile functions ahead-of-time by [telling it what signatures to expect](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#eager-compilation), but there's little benefit to doing so.

Also, `diff.microseconds` is just the microseconds component, omitting seconds or days. You need `diff.total_seconds()`, which gives a float representing the total duration of the timedelta in seconds, or `diff / timedelta(microseconds=1)` for a value in microseconds.